# Can the overlay be used as a popup?

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

In Drupal 6 there was the Modal Frame API which made it to Drupal 7 core. However, I'm not sure how leverage the Overlay independent of being an administration screen. Is there any information about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually yes - overlay might be used too if needed. I have just done a quick write-up on this: http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-open-standard-content-pages-in-drupal-7s-administrative-overlay

Answer (score 2):

No. 
However, core also contains jQuery UI Dialog, so you can use that (Views and Media both use it)

Comment: Are there any decent tutorials on how to use jQuery UI Dialog with Drupal 7?

Comment: Nothing especial about using it in Drupal 7, D7 just provides you the files, you do everything else yourself, like in every tutorial.

Comment: See drupal_add_library() -- you should use that function to add the resources needed by the jQuery UI Dialog (or any other jQuery UI components) to the current page.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial might help: [How to Add a jQuery UI Dialog to Drupal 7](http://dansilvercentral.com/tutorial-add-jquery-ui-popup-drupal-7). The [Simple Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module might prove useful too.